# Java 1.7 String.intern() is not InternedStrings in JVM or i am wrong

Tags: java, literals

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>   A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>   When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.
>   It follows that for any two strings s and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is true if and only if s.equals(t) is true.

This means that literals are cached in String class in its private pool, but JVM achitecture says about InternedStrings:

> Interned Strings (String Table)
>   The Java Language Specification requires that identical string literals, that contain the same sequence of Unicode code points, must refer to the same instance of String. In addition if String.intern() is called on an instance of String a reference must be returned that would be identical to the reference return if the string was a literal. The following therefore holds true:
>   ("j" + "v" + "m").intern() == "jvm"
>   In the Hotspot JVM interned string are held in the string table, which is a Hashtable mapping object pointers to symbols (i.e. Hashtable), and is held in the permanent generation. For both the symbol table (see above) and the string table all entries are held in a canonicalized form to improve efficiency and ensure each entry only appears once.
>   String literals are automatically interned by the compiler and added into the symbol table when the class is loaded. In addition instances of the String class can be explicitly interned by calling String.intern(). When String.intern() is called, if the symbol table already contains the string then a reference to this is returned, if not the string is added to the string table and its reference is returned.

My question is where exactly literals / strings are stored - in JVM -> PermGen -> InternedStrings as JVM docs says or in String class in some private collection as String API says?

Comment: The JVM is free to put interned strings wherever it wants so long as it maintains the Java-level semantics (reference equality of interned strings and literals).  Whatever answer you get, it's likely to be out of date in a couple of JVM versions.  Do you have an actual problem you hope to solve using the answer, or are you just curious?

Comment: Curious + i am using oracle java 1.7

Comment: The interned strings are just Strings.  The difference is that they persist (sort of) forever, and if you `intern()` multiple character-identical Strings you keep getting the exact same String back as was returned by the very first `intern()` operation for that character value.  How the JVM performs this magic is not your worry.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.6 and below it was permgen. Starting in 7 it went to the heap, and I know one of the point releases in 7 had some significant changes in the way it worked.

*edit*

Found this http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/ The big change came in 7u40.

*edit* *edit*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/enhancements-7.html

```
Synopsis: In JDK 7, interned strings are no longer allocated in
the permanent generation of the Java heap, but are instead
allocated in the main part of the Java heap (known as the young
and old generations), along with the other objects created by the
application. This change will result in more data residing in the
main Java heap, and lessw data in the permanent generation, and
thus may require heap sizes to be adjusted. Most applications
will see only relatively small differences in heap usage due to
this change, but larger applications that load many classes or
make heavy use of the String.intern() method will see more
significant differences.  RFE: 6962931
```

Comment: Great answer. And what about String.intern() API is it old or lying or what

Comment: Also - this article is wrong about java 1.7 and InternedStrings - they are told to be stored in Permgen in java 7. http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html#string_table  am I right or misanderstanding something?

Comment: @user1308908 According to Oracle (see edit edit) above, it was changed in 1.7

Answer (score 0):

API says that it is maintained by class String (means - on heap). From Java 8, Permgen is removed. Hence its stored on Heap.

Comment: Hmm. But PermGen is also where Classloader loads classes definitions, their methods, constants etc is that right? So where classes and methods will be loaded in java 8?